# How can I increase FPS when detecting aruco markers?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, aruco

When I using aruco markers, I am getting very low fps(10~15). Firstly I showed the FPS info, marker position, marker attitude, camera position and camera attitude on the detection screen. With this way, I get ~10 FPS. Then I removed all texts except FPS info. It was better(~13 FPS) but still not enough. I need at least 25 FPS. How can I increase FPS?

Resolution: 640x480

**aruco_pose_estimation.py**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco
import sys, time, math

#--- Define Tag
id_to_find  = 3
marker_size  = 10 #- [cm]

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#------- ROTATIONS https://www.learnopencv.com/rotation-matrix-to-euler-angles/
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Checks if a matrix is a valid rotation matrix.
def isRotationMatrix(R):
    Rt = np.transpose(R)
    shouldBeIdentity = np.dot(Rt, R)
    I = np.identity(3, dtype=R.dtype)
    n = np.linalg.norm(I - shouldBeIdentity)
    return n < 1e-6

# Calculates rotation matrix to euler angles
# The result is the same as MATLAB except the order
# of the euler angles ( x and z are swapped ).
def rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R):
    assert (isRotationMatrix(R))

    sy = math.sqrt(R[0, 0] * R[0, 0] + R[1, 0] * R[1, 0])

    singular = sy < 1e-6

    if not singular:
        x = math.atan2(R[2, 1], R[2, 2])
        y = math.atan2(-R[2, 0], sy)
        z = math.atan2(R[1, 0], R[0, 0])
    else:
        x = math.atan2(-R[1, 2], R[1, 1])
        y = math.atan2(-R[2, 0], sy)
        z = 0

    return np.array([x, y, z])

#--- Get the camera calibration path
calib_path  = ""
camera_matrix   = np.loadtxt(calib_path+'cameraMatrix_raspi.txt', delimiter=',')
camera_distortion   = np.loadtxt(calib_path+'cameraDistortion_raspi.txt', delimiter=',')

#--- 180 deg rotation matrix around the x axis
R_flip  = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=np.float32)
R_flip[0,0] = 1.0
R_flip[1,1] =-1.0
R_flip[2,2] =-1.0

#--- Define the aruco dictionary
aruco_dict  = aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(aruco.DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL)
#aruco_dict  = aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(aruco.DICT_4X4_250)
parameters  = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()


#--- Capture the videocamera (this may also be a video or a picture)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#-- Set the camera size as the one it was calibrated with
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 40)

#-- Font for the text in the image
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN

prev_frame_time = time.time()

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray    = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #-- remember, OpenCV stores color images in Blue, Green, Red

    #-- Find all the aruco markers in the image
    corners, ids, rejected = aruco.detectMarkers(image=gray, dictionary=aruco_dict, parameters=parameters,
                          cameraMatrix=camera_matrix, distCoeff=camera_distortion)

    if ids is not None:
    
        ret = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, marker_size, camera_matrix, camera_distortion)

        #-- Unpack the output, get only the first
        rvec, tvec = ret[0][0,0,:], ret[1][0,0,:]

        #-- Draw the detected marker and put a reference frame over it
        aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners)
        aruco.drawAxis(frame, camera_matrix, camera_distortion, rvec, tvec, 10)

        #-- Print the tag position in camera frame
        str_position = "MARKER Position x=%4.0f  y=%4.0f  z=%4.0f"%(tvec[0], tvec[1], tvec[2])
        cv2.putText(frame, str_position, (0, 400), font, 1.3, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        #-- Obtain the rotation matrix tag->camera
        R_ct    = np.matrix(cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)[0])
        R_tc    = R_ct.T

        #-- Get the attitude in terms of euler 321 (Needs to be flipped first)
        roll_marker, pitch_marker, yaw_marker = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R_flip*R_tc)

        #-- Print the marker's attitude respect to camera frame
        str_attitude = "MARKER Attitude r=%4.0f  p=%4.0f  y=%4.0f"%(math.degrees(roll_marker),math.degrees(pitch_marker),
                        math.degrees(yaw_marker))
        cv2.putText(frame, str_attitude, (0, 420), font, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        #-- Now get Position and attitude f the camera respect to the marker
        pos_camera = -R_tc*np.matrix(tvec).T
        str_position = "CAMERA Position x=%4.0f  y=%4.0f  z=%4.0f"%(pos_camera[0], pos_camera[1], pos_camera[2])
        cv2.putText(frame, str_position, (0, 440), font, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        #-- Get the attitude of the camera respect to the frame
        roll_camera, pitch_camera, yaw_camera = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R_flip*R_tc)
        str_attitude = "CAMERA Attitude r=%4.0f  p=%4.0f  y=%4.0f"%(math.degrees(roll_camera),math.degrees(pitch_camera),
                        math.degrees(yaw_camera))
        cv2.putText(frame, str_attitude, (0, 460), font, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

    #calculate the FPS and display on frame
    new_frame_time = time.time()
    fps = 1/(new_frame_time - prev_frame_time)
    prev_frame_time = new_frame_time
    cv2.putText(frame, "FPS" + str(int(fps)), (0,360), font, 1.3, (100, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

    #--- Display the frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    #--- use 'q' to quit
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    break
```

.

[image]

.

**After removed texts**

[image]

Comment: have you *profiled* your code? unless you know exactly how much time is spent on what parts of the code, you can't make any improvements at all. -- to answer the title: you can't. the implementation of aruco could be improved but you'd have to change C++ code (and know what to improve, if there is anything to improve at all).

Comment: Try running `htop` to see if all 4 of your CPU cores are being used fully.